# What happens when I complete all heists and replay them?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have done all heists and want to replay the fleeca job. If I redo it and complete it will I still have all heist unlocked or do I have to start over?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have completed each heist, you are free to replay them whenever you want.

Do note: Starting one of the previous heists will start a heist "save" like usual, causing you to not be able to host other ones until you complete/quit your current one.